# execute main.js from a sub directory

Tags: electron

Why on earth can I not move my main.js file into a sub directory and have electron build from the that sub directory? for instance my file structure:

```
app
|_package.json
|_node_modules
|_src
  |_main.js
  |_index.html
  |_renderer.js
  |_...
```

My package.json:

```
"main":"main.js",
"scripts" : {
  "start": "electron ./src"
}
```

When I run **start** electron launches the intro screen("to start your application run ...") and not the application I created at **./src**. Is there a package out there that allows for this to happen? is there something I'm missing in the package.json file?

Been a while since I posted to SO but this one got me stumped / its not clearly documented on Electron's site(you'd think it would be in architecture). I do see in the quickstart about file structure but it doesn't say I can't do as I illustrated above^ It's not really a big deal I just hate when Im forced into a specific file structure.

Answer (score 10):

The Electron application I am developing makes also use of a `main.js` file located in a sub-directory, and this is how it would be documented in your `package.json` file:

```
"main":"src/main.js",
"scripts" : {
  "start": "electron ."
}
```

I guess this is because `npm` needs the correct relative path of the startup script in `package.json`...

There may be also some relevant information in [Writing Your First Electron App](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app).